# Use max() and left() in the same command

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have data that looks like this and the format of the values is always the same.

```
entries

12aa
39aa
45ba
18ac
51cc
```

I want to get the max integer from the column without a helper column.

In this example, the formula would return 51.

Comment: what version of excel?

Comment: Most recent version

Comment: You show a tag for `excel 2010`.  That is not the most recent version.  Which is it?

Comment: My mistake, it's the most recent version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the format is always the same, as you show, with two digits and two alphabet, then simply:

```
=MAX(--LEFT(myRange,2))
```

Comment: What do you call the -- part of the formula? I've not seen that before

Comment: @Cauder It is called a `double unary` and has the same effect as the `VALUE` function